# How can I apply grammatical gender in Choices?

Tags: python, django, django-models, gettext

I use *Model Utils* to define statuses in Django :

```
class MetaData(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel, SoftDeletableModel):
    STATUS = Choices(('Draft', _('Draft')),
                     ('Submitted', _('Submitted')),
                     ('Reviewed', _('Reviewed')),
                     ('Final', _('Final')),)
```

These statuses may eventually apply to a masculine or feminine object (in French), and I don't understand how to define pgettext contexts here.

Thank you very much !

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: status is used for portfolio and achievement objects. For example in templates with status = 'Reviewed' will translate in French : `{{ achievement.status }}` -> 'Révisée' / `{{ portfolio.status }}` -> 'Révisé'

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution by adding a dummy variable to the class for each status context, for example :

`portfolio_reviewed = pgettext('portfolio', 'Reviewed')`

Answer (score 0):

The answer you had provided yourself is an unnecessary hack. Message contexts are not intended for such use.

Why don't you just use this:

```
portfolio_reviewed = gettext('Reviewed portfolio')
```

Compare that to your version:

```
portfolio_reviewed = pgettext('portfolio', 'Reviewed')
```

It is even shorter. And it has the additional benefit that translators would not need any additional information about what the context `portfolio` has been used (read: abused) here for.

And why is it a hack? Your solution suggests that you are assembling/concatenating translations which is a well-known recipe for trouble. Other languages may and will require different word orders in a sentence.

Your hack will probably work for Finnish because it has just one grammatical gender but probably not for German or Russian with three.  You should just avoid any assumptions about the syntax of other languages when internationalizing software.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree pretty much wth everything, but the problem is that the `status` variable appears in contexts where the concatenation "Portfolio reviewed" or "Achievement reviewed" would be redundant. For example in the `Table of achievements : [achievement_name, achievement_status]`. It would be redundant to have "Achievement reviewed" in each row instead of simply "Reviewed" since the context is quite clear about that. And the only reason I need to do this is **because** of grammatical gender changes from one context to another.

Comment: Redundancies are quite normal in the context of localized messages. I think it's okay.